# MacOS apps: Build number(CFBundleVersion) changes from one dot to two dots format would be treated as increasing?

Tags: app-store

Does anyone know if build number(CFBundleVersion) changes from one dot to two dots format would be treated as increasing? For instance, from 7003.0901 to 12.09030.09110

Based on https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016603-CH1-TWO_NAMING_CONVENTIONS_FOR_VERSION_NUMBERS_AND_BUILD_NUMBERS

> “For macOS apps, build numbers must monotonically increase even across
>   different versions. In other words, for macOS apps you cannot use the
>   same build numbers again in different release trains. iOS apps have no
>   such restriction and you can re-use the same build numbers again in
>   different release trains.”

Thanks